# How to return strings that are sorted by their number(using Linq) in c#

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, oop, return-value

I have a question about how to print only texts that are sorted by number using Linq

for example, if I wanted to print only the names of the mountain, which would be sorted by the height of the mountain

**NOTE:** I just invented a Mountain class that would contain only 2 variables - the height and the name of the mountain (including the constructor, toString() etc...)

**input:**

```
Mountain mountain1 = new Mountain("Mountain1",3000);
Mountain mountain2 = new Mountain("Mountain2",2000);
Mountain mountain3 = new Mountain("Mountain3",6500);
```

**output:**

```
Mountain3
Mountain1
Mountain2
```

Comment: Use a `List<Mountain>` or whatever `IEnumerable<T>` and use [`.OrderBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-6.0)

Comment: `var names = mountainList.OrderBy(x=>x.Height).Select(y=>y.Name)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you can you make a List/Array ect. with those objects, you can order them By Property. By default it would return ascending values, thats why in your case you would need `OrderByDescending`.

```
var mountains = new []
{
   new Mountain("Mountain1",3000),
   new Mountain("Mountain2",2000),
   new Mountain("Mountain3",6500),
};

mountains.OrderByDescending(x => x.Height).Select(x => x.Name);
```

The code as a working Fiddle can be found here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/szA14I

Comment: Some extra context would be nice. (for example using linq)

Comment: All you need to know  I've already posted.I would like to sort the Mountains  by their Height,but print just the Name of the mountain